# virtualenv is installed in my machine but still getting "not recognised as internal or external command "

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper-win directories in my machine using commands

> pip install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper-win

And also when I run

> pip show virtualenv

It is displaying everything about it .But when I try to run

> mkvirtualenv my_project

It's showing me this error **'mkvirtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
Idk why ...
please help me out .

Comment: Are you trying to create a virtual environment for your project?

Comment: Yes @manhvd , i am trying to create environment for my Django project

Comment: Please try again with command: virtualenv my_project

Comment: Thanks @manhvd  it worked . Virtualenv directory was not there in path .so when i added that directory to path it worked .